Using tools with Azure OpenAI batch jobs
When I submit a batch job using Azure OpenAI 'Batch jobs' and include 'tools' in the specification of each job, I receive a response that appears to ignore tools specification.
Is there any way to use tools with Azure OpenAI batch jobs?

This is not documented well, but it appears that at this moment this feature is not yet supported.
A relevant thread for non-batch calls is here.
A relevant feature request on GitHub is here.
